# Using mvn install:install

Tags: maven, installation

I have a multi-module structure with a parent and child dependencies. There are about 20 sub modules. I want to run mvn clean verify to get quick feedback on my build and then install the packages for which I'm trying to use: mvn install:install.
Below is a snippet of the parent pom:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

However once I run mvn install:install, I get the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install (default-cli) on project sae.domain: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]

Is there something else I have to add / change to my pom / goals etc or am I missing something here? I tried these things based on various inputs available on the internet and hit have a deadend I'm afraid!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding modules to your parent pom file

```
<modules>
        <module>simple-weather</module>
        <module>simple-webapp</module>
</modules>
```

Here is a tutorial to build a multi-module project

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html

an example Parent Project POM file from the above tutorial

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Multi Chapter Simple Parent Project</name>

<modules>
    <module>simple-weather</module>
    <module>simple-webapp</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to install it, run

```
mvn install
```

instead of mvn install:install.

Comment: running mvn install runs all the previous steps because it's a life cycle phase and not a specific goal- which takes a lot of time & I want to avoid that - that's why I'm looking at options to just install without running the previous steps.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to add those extra plugin info and running it as

```
    mvn jar:jar install:install
```

worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as above, if you just want to install it, run

```
mvn install
```

If you user idea, like this:
[image: screenshot]